# PHP POST data not coming through with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: php

I'm having trouble getting my form's post data to come through.  As this code stands, the file uploads, but I don't have any post data for the other form fields.  I noticed that if I get rid of multipart/form-data enctype, it will not upload (obviously) but I DO get the post data to come through for the other fields. Any ideas on why this is?

The page where this code occurs is index.php?page=page1&upload=1

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?page=page1&upload=2" method="post">
Select Location: <select name="location">
    <option>Select Location</option>
    <option value="N">North</option>
    <option value="S">South</option>
    <option value="E">East</option>
    <option value="W">West</option>
</select><br />
Upload File: <input name="ufile" type="file" id="ufile" size="50" /><br />
<b><u>Sunday</u></b> Date: <select name="month">
    <option> - Month - </option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">Febuary</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="day">
    <option> - Day - </option>
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    <option value="04">4</option>
    <option value="05">5</option>
    <option value="06">6</option>
    <option value="07">7</option>
    <option value="08">8</option>
    <option value="09">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="year">
<?php
    $optionyear = date("Y",time());
    $currentyear = $optionyear;
    while($optionyear != 1990) {
        echo "<option value=\"".$optionyear."\"";
        if($optionyear == $currentyear) {
            echo " selected";
        }
        echo ">".$optionyear."</option>";
        $optionyear--;
    }
?>
</select><br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" /><br />
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

U can get your upload data with `$_FILES[]` and other data with `$_POST[]`

Try

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES['ufile']);
echo "</pre>";
```

By the way where is close tag for `<form>` element?

Comment: Here's the output I got:
    Array
    (
    )

Thanks for your help!